# How to multiply only integers in a pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, types, series

I would like to solve what I thought should be a fairly simple problem. I want to take a pandas series:

```
'a'
10 
'b'
'someword' 
'c'
20 
'd'
'sometext'
30
```

and multiply only the numeric values by 2, excluding the strings.

However, when I try writing a mask for my series:

```
ser[dtype(ser) == int]
```

the function dtype(ser) will return only a single value (in this case False) instead of a boolean mask as expected. I know when doing the same with a data frame I can use df.select_dtypes. Is there a similar function for series?

Note that I am specifically looking for the "simple/pandorable" solution. I know that I could just as well iterate over the series, but I want to find a way to write a simple mask for the series instead.

Comment: What is the Series? Could you please add it in a format that could be copied and pasted in .py file?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of masking you can use a lambda function that multiplies the integers only and leaves the other dtypes as they are:

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> ser = pd.Series(['a', 10,'b', 'someword', 'c', 20, 'd', 'sometext', 30])
```

Sample series:

```
0           a
1          10
2           b
3    someword
4           c
5          20
6           d
7    sometext
8          30
dtype: object
```

---

```
>>> ser = ser.apply(lambda x: x*2 if isinstance(x, int) else x)
```

Output:

```
0           a
1          20
2           b
3    someword
4           c
5          40
6           d
7    sometext
8          60
dtype: object
```

If you would like to use masking you can do the following:

```
isnumeric = ser.astype(str).str.isnumeric()
ser[isnumeric] = ser[isnumeric]*2
ser
```

Output:

```
0           a
1          20
2           b
3    someword
4           c
5          40
6           d
7    sometext
8          60
dtype: object
```

Comment: This does it! Not the most intuitive way to make the mask, but thank you for the answer nonetheless. :)

Comment: Glad it helped. You can also accept and upvote answers if you find them helpful. Good luck!